# Why does the save button not work out in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Hisya
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        englishTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        bmTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        mathTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        scienceTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        geoTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        EletterTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        GletterTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        BletterTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        MletterTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        SletterTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        averageTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        gpaTF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI Black", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("GRADE CALCULATOR");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("English               :");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Mathematics     :");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Science              :");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Geography        :");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Bahasa Melayu :");

        englishTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                englishTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        bmTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bmTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        mathTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                mathTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        scienceTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                scienceTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        geoTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                geoTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        EletterTF.setEditable(false);
        EletterTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                EletterTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        GletterTF.setEditable(false);
        GletterTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                GletterTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        BletterTF.setEditable(false);
        BletterTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BletterTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        MletterTF.setEditable(false);
        MletterTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                MletterTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        SletterTF.setEditable(false);
        SletterTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SletterTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Average :");

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("GPA        :");

        averageTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                averageTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        gpaTF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                gpaTFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("letter");

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Calculate");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Save Grade");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 281, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(12, 12, 12))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(11, 11, 11))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton2))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(scienceTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(SletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(mathTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(MletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(geoTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(GletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(bmTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(BletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(gpaTF))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(averageTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(englishTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(EletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGap(0, 40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(geoTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(GletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(englishTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(EletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(mathTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(MletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(scienceTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(SletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addComponent(averageTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addComponent(bmTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(BletterTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addComponent(gpaTF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void englishTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void bmTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void mathTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void scienceTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void geoTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void EletterTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void GletterTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void BletterTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void MletterTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void SletterTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void averageTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void gpaTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // Calculate all the grade
        String englishScore, mathScore,scienceScore,geoScore,bmScore;
        double average;
        double gpa = 0;
        
        englishScore = englishTF.getText();
        mathScore = mathTF.getText();
        scienceScore = scienceTF.getText();
        geoScore = geoTF.getText();
        bmScore = bmTF.getText();
        
        double english = Double.parseDouble(englishScore);
        double math = Double.parseDouble(mathScore);
        double science = Double.parseDouble(scienceScore); 
        double geo = Double.parseDouble(geoScore);
        double bm = Double.parseDouble(bmScore);
        
        average = ((english + math + science + geo + bm) / 5);
        
        if (english >= 90){
           EletterTF.setText("A");
           gpa = gpa + 4.0;
        } else if (english >= 80 && english < 90){
            EletterTF.setText("A-");
            gpa = gpa + 3.5;
        } else if (english >= 70 && english < 80){
            EletterTF.setText("B");
            gpa = gpa + 3.0;
        } else if (english >= 60 && english < 70){
            EletterTF.setText("B-");
            gpa = gpa + 2.5;
        } else if (english >= 50 && english < 60){
            EletterTF.setText("C");
            gpa = gpa + 2.0;
        } else if (english >= 40 && english < 50){
            EletterTF.setText("D");
            gpa = gpa + 1.0;
        } else {
            EletterTF.setText("F");
            gpa = gpa + 0;
        }
        
        if (math >= 90){
           MletterTF.setText("A");
           gpa = gpa + 4.0;
        } else if (math >= 80 && math < 90){
            MletterTF.setText("A-");
            gpa = gpa + 3.5;
        } else if (math >= 70 && math < 80){
            MletterTF.setText("B");
            gpa = gpa + 3.0;
        } else if (math >= 60 && math < 70){
            MletterTF.setText("B-");
            gpa = gpa + 2.5;
        } else if (math >= 50 && math < 60){
            MletterTF.setText("C");
            gpa = gpa + 2.0;
        } else if (math >= 40 && math < 50){
            MletterTF.setText("D");
            gpa = gpa + 1.0;
        } else {
            MletterTF.setText("F");
            gpa = gpa + 0;
        }
     
        if (science >= 90){
           SletterTF.setText("A");
           gpa = gpa + 4.0;
        } else if ( science >= 80 &&science < 90){
            SletterTF.setText("A-");
            gpa = gpa + 3.5;
        } else if (science >= 70 && science < 80){
            SletterTF.setText("B");
            gpa = gpa + 3.0;
        } else if (science >= 60 && science < 70){
            SletterTF.setText("B-");
            gpa = gpa + 2.5;
        } else if (science >= 50 && science < 60){
            SletterTF.setText("C");
            gpa = gpa + 2.0;
        } else if (science >= 40 && science < 50){
            SletterTF.setText("D");
            gpa = gpa + 1.0;
        } else {
            SletterTF.setText("F");
            gpa = gpa + 0;
        }
        
        if (geo >= 90){
           GletterTF.setText("A");
           gpa = gpa + 4.0;
        } else if ( geo >= 80 && geo < 90){
            GletterTF.setText("A-");
            gpa = gpa + 3.5;
        } else if ( geo >= 70 && geo < 80){
            GletterTF.setText("B");
            gpa = gpa + 3.0;
        } else if (geo >= 60 && geo < 70){
            GletterTF.setText("B-");
            gpa = gpa + 2.5;
        } else if (geo >= 50 && geo < 60){
            GletterTF.setText("C");
            gpa = gpa + 2.0;
        } else if (geo >= 40 && geo < 50){
            GletterTF.setText("D");
            gpa = gpa + 1.0;
        } else {
            GletterTF.setText("F");
            gpa = gpa + 0;
        }
        
        if (bm >= 90){
           BletterTF.setText("A");
           gpa = gpa + 4.0;
        } else if ( bm >= 80 && bm < 90){
            BletterTF.setText("A-");
            gpa = gpa + 3.5;
        } else if ( bm >= 70 && bm < 80){
            BletterTF.setText("B");
            gpa = gpa + 3.0;
        } else if (bm >= 60 && bm < 70){
            BletterTF.setText("B-");
            gpa = gpa + 2.5;
        } else if (bm >= 50 && bm < 60){
            BletterTF.setText("C");
            gpa = gpa + 2.0;
        } else if (bm >= 40 && bm < 50){
            BletterTF.setText("D");
            gpa = gpa + 1.0;
        } else {
            BletterTF.setText("F");
            gpa = gpa + 0;
        }
        gpa = gpa/5;
        
        gpaTF.setText(Double.toString(gpa));
        averageTF.setText(Double.toString(average));
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String english = englishTF.getText();
        String math = mathTF.getText();
        String science = scienceTF.getText();
        String geo = geoTF.getText();
        String bm = bmTF.getText(); 
        String average = averageTF.getText();
        String gpa = gpaTF.getText();
        try
        {
         FileWriter Writer = new FileWriter("grade.txt",true); 
         Writer.write (""+english+" "+math+" "+science+" "+geo+" "+bm+" "+average+" "+gpa+" ");
         Writer.write(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
         Writer.close();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Success !");
         setVisible(false);
         new InsertData().setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error :( ");  
        }
        
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField BletterTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField EletterTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField GletterTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField MletterTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField SletterTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField averageTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField bmTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField englishTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField geoTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField gpaTF;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JTextField mathTF;
    private javax.swing.JTextField scienceTF;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private static class InsertData {

        public InsertData() {
        }

        private void setVisible(boolean b) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Why does the save button not work?"* [Edit] to add a [mre] & someone might be along to help soon, now I've retagged this. An MRE would be (much, much) shorter than 580 lines of code.

Comment: As an aside. While debugging, and in lieu of adding logging to, a `catch`, change `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error :( ");` to `e.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error :( ");`. Without that exception information, we are programming blind.